# Why won't my canvas upload to the server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, upload

Trying to make a canvas where you can add stuff like a background, stickers and text, and then be able to upload it to the server the canvas is hosted on.

Followed different guides and codepens, and have everything working except for the upload to server part.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  console.log("reader   " + reader);
  reader.onload = function(f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
      var oImg = img.set({
        left: 70,
        top: 100,
        width: 250,
        height: 200,
        angle: 0
      }).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

$('#fill').change(function() {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (obj) {
    obj.setFill($(this).val());
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
});

$('#font').change(function() {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (obj) {
    obj.setFontFamily($(this).val());
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
});

function addText() {
  var oText = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
  });

  canvas.add(oText);
  canvas.setActiveObject(oText);
  $('#fill, #font').trigger('change');
  oText.bringToFront();
}

document.querySelector('#txt').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  document.querySelector('#preview').src = canvas.toDataURL();
};



canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
  fontFamily: 'arial black',
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
}));


function Shirt_Load(img) {
  var shirt = img.src;
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(shirt, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    width: 600,
    height: 600
  });

}
var photo = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'photo_upload.php',
  data: {
    photo: photo
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

HTML
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="file">
<input type="color" value="blue" id="fill" />
<select id="font">
  <option>arial</option>
  <option>tahoma</option>
  <option>times new roman</option>
</select>
<button onclick="addText()">Add Custom Text</button>
<br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
<a href='' id='txt' target="_blank">Preview</a>
<br />
<img id="preview" />

<button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="photo_upload.php">Submit</button>
</form>

<img onclick="Shirt_Load(this);" src="http://www.koffid.nl/pics/bg1.png" width="100" height="100" />
<img onclick="Shirt_Load(this);" src="http://www.koffid.nl/pics/mk.png" width="100" height="100" />
```

and the php file:

```html
<?php
 
 $data = $_POST['photo'];
 list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
 list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
 $data = base64_decode($data);

 mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ./photos);

 file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ./photos/.time().'.png', $data);
 die;
?>
```

Any help would eb much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: And the pen: http://codepen.io/drduval/pen/QNqYor

Comment: I would suggest to send image as raw POST data, not url-encoded POST parameter

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I need a little hand holding here, which part of the code should be changed?

Comment: Have you checked console (F12) to see if you get any errors? (e.g. like security error, type error...)

Answer (score 0):

One thing:

```
var photo = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'photo_upload.php',
  data: {
    photo: photo
  }
});
```

should be:

```
var photo = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'photo_upload.php',
  data: {
    'photo': photo
  }
});
```

Comment: Both are the same. Quotes around the property name are only needed if the latter is not valid JavaScript identifier ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals))

Comment: Adding the quotes didn't do anything sadly. Thanks though!